# How can I pass the current referenced object in form collection in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I use this code

```
$builder->add('userTasks','collection',array('type' => new UserTaskType()));
```

This is working fine

userTasks will be a collection different userTask objects which will in turn create the form.

Now is there any way that i can pass that individual UserTask object in the constructor like this

```
$builder->add('userTasks','collection',array('type' => new UserTaskType($userTask)));
```

so that i can use that to generate Label for the form.

Is it possible

If i use  `$user->UseTasks` then that will be a collection of all tasks but i only want that object whose form is being created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to adjust the form based on the actual data object which the form will be bound to?  It is one of the those simple sounding requirements that is actually a bit involved.

You need to use the form event system:
http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html

It's not so bad once you have worked through it.

===

To answer the first comment:

```
public function preSetData(DataEvent $event)
{
    $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();
```

$data will be your object, in this case a $userTask.

Comment: i tried that example but still dont get where is that object in that code